# Displaying fetched data in different section than store

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have been unable to find any answer for this, which makes me think I am missing something extremely simple so apologies in advance. I am self taught and currently still learning the basics.

My dilemma is in displaying results from a fetch request. I have a table view and want to display the data in section 1, but the data's index path is section 0. Every sample I've seen has only showed when the table view index path and core data index path match, not any when they are different. What is the best practice for solving this? Is there a way to save the index path to section 1 at creation? Is there a way to fetch from a different index path than is being displayed? Am I missing something else entirely?

Again apologies if this is a simple question, I am teaching myself and understand I am likely doing a great deal wrong.

Comment: You can create the indexPath for section 1 using IndexPath(row:yourRow, section: 1), see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34746518/3985749) for example.

Comment: Use the sectionNameKeyPath and NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate protocol methods.